# Getting total value of same id and display the final answer as an json array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a Json array as follows

```
$scope.array = [{id:"1", tot:20},{id:"2", tot:30},{id:"1", tot:20},{id:"3", tot:50}];
```

I want to get the sum of tot belonging to same id and display the final answer as another Json array as follows

output:

```
[{id:"1", total:40},{id:"2", total:30},{id:"3", total:50}]
```

How can I achieve this using angularjs?

Comment: I would say AngularJS has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd solve this by using **`Array.reduce`**. Like this:

```js
var array = [{id:"1", tot:20},{id:"2", tot:30},{id:"1", tot:20},{id:"3", tot:50}];

var res = array.reduce(function (agg, obj) {
  var objForId = agg.filter(function (idObj) { return idObj.id === obj.id})[0]
  
  if (objForId) {
    objForId.total += obj.tot;
  } else {
    agg.push({
      id: obj.id,
      total: obj.tot
    })
  }

  return agg;
}, [])

console.log(res)
```